# Ask for/about a new company car without appearing as nagging/careless

Tags: human-resources, company-car

One of the benefits at my work is a company car (leasing). The employee is free to pick a car which matches or is less then the projected budget (for that employee). I currently have mine for nearly 4 years.

Two years ago I asked for a bigger/better car due to the increase responsibility. Although me asking was partially unfounded and I had no right to it, they said they would give me a new car when one got available within my "category".

Fast forward one year later. During my evaluation, my boss thought I already had a new car. I corrected her and she advised me to contact HR. Because normally they don't allow cars to get beyond 130.000 km. HR said they wanted to complete the contract as they saw no reason to upgrade or prematurely sell the car. Me, having matured quite a lot by then (Been through quite a lot that year), accepted and found their reasons founded.

Today my car is at nearly 172.000 km. The leasing company demands that the car returns either at 180.000km or after 4 years (which would be halfway november). So I know the (new) car won't ever make it time. New cars in Belgium tend to have an average delivery time of 3 months.

This leaves me with a problem. I don't really want to nag for a new car nor do I want to resemble careless. So I'm currently faced with a dilemma.

- Should I "forget" that the contract expires halfway november. And see what happens then. Possibly looking careless & getting HR in trouble or forcing them to costly temporary solution (short-term-lease).
- Or should I remind them that the contract expires in 2 months? If so how would I tell them without seeming nagging or desperate for a new car?

Some side-notes

- I do a reasonably amout of km/week (around 900km) and I don't know the leasing policy with regards to exceeding the maximum allowed kilometers
- I can't tell whether HR is aware of the situation. I haven't heard from them (with regards to my salary/benefits) in about two years

Any input is greatly appreciated.

P.S. my yearly evaluation (including my "expected" salary raise) is always at the end of November. So after the contract expiration date. And I really like to prevent agitating my boss or HR.

[This](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/63406/how-to-ask-for-something-optional-subtly-without-appearing-demanding-or-entitled) question comes quite close but not quite the same

Comment: Is the car essential to your position?(F.e. sales or such)

Comment: @cbll yes. I work everyday at the offices of clients (IT-consultant) and i'm never in my company HQ. Last time I was no less then 2 years ago.

Comment: I don;t think that reminding them that the contract expires in 2 months would be considered nagging.

Comment: Then I'd say it's fairly reasonable to notify HR about the contract running out, and request a new car, especially since you not having one would mean it can affect clients..

Comment: @Pete I'm willing to wait without a doubt. In my current family situation I don't need a bigger car. The problem is don't know if they are aware that the problem is about to expire.  Also "slightly" might my not applicable to my situation. I do about 900km a week.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to talk with your boss first (and probably your HR).

It seems, regardless of everything you wrote about promotions and evaluations, that your car is going to quickly reach the number of miles the leasing company requires a return by (or the date). Additionally, if the contract expires in two months you *really* need to do this, if cars take three to receive.

Two years is a long time between questions. It's not nagging **unless HR is well aware of the situation already**. But given that the last time you mentioned it was a year ago (during your evaluation) and to HR it was two years ago, it won't be nagging.

Nagging is after HR says "we'll work on it" checking in every day for the next two months. Not getting clarity on how the process works.

My recommendation is to first talk to your boss and clarify how the new car process works. It seems you do not fully understand this, given that you are getting close or past when you need the process to start. It is possible HR is automatically pursuing the process.

Likely your boss will recommend you followup with HR. Your boss will be able to give you some guidance on how to approach this, but if you haven't talked to HR in two years and your boss in one year, it is likely to be a simple conversation with them.

Comment: Thank you for your splendid insight. I'm seeing my boss tomorrow for a lunch-meeting (about a side-project) and i'll ask him after all the important matters have been discussed.

Comment: @User999999 somewhat unrelated, but you should probably try to have some sort of regular 1/1 meeting with your boss as that is a great time to discuss questions like this, too.

Comment: A good point but somewhat hard in our situation. We are with 300 employees within our company spread to clients throughout Belgium. She once admitted that she wants to stand closer to her employees. But as we are this much spread, it's quite hard to achieve.

Comment: @User999999 it's 2016. Phones, skype, google hangouts, etc all make this really easy. I've actually never seen my boss in person yet and of my last 4 managers, was only able to have in person 1/1s with one of them ;-)

Comment: You're right. As an IT-professional i'm consistently working with such devices/products. And yet this simple solution has eluded me all this time.... :-) Thx for the great info

Comment: +1 for this answer. For OP: keep in mind that leasing companies will sell the car, and they have these strict rules such as a max. amount of kms, age, etc to be able to sell the car at all. If HR doesn't want to understand this.. well I would also get in touch with the lease company.

Answer (score 0):

It'd be careless of you to allow it to fall out of the contract/terms of the contract. Tell HR and make them aware the reason you're telling them is because of this contract issue. It likely says something in your contract about not needlessly costing the company money.

As a side note add the fact you'd like a particular car too.